# Importing From Chainlink: Source Not Found. File out of allowed directories

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I have run into this issue multiple times. Everytime I try to import something from github and adding it usign the yarn package manager I am shown with the error below. This time I have been working on a Solidity contract and wanted to import something from the chianlink repository. One workaround I discovered was copying the required files and including them on the project directly but I do not want to do that. So, I wanted a solution to fix this rather than working around it.

I am using the following:

```
VsCode
WSL 2.0
Hardhat Framework
Yarn Package Manager
```

So the issue is while I am trying to import:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol";
```

I am shown:

```
Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol" file outside of allowed directories.
```

I have already done:

```
yarn add --dev @chainlink/contracts
```

Here is my package.json file contents:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.5.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.7.1",
    "hardhat": "^2.11.2",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.6.1",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.18",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "solhint": "^3.3.7",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the cause of this issue? And how to fix it?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109758/file-outside-of-allowed-directories-on-brownie-compile-command

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the full relative path to the directory. For example if your directory has a contracts folder and node_module folder and your contract lives within the contracts folder, your import statement for your chainlink contract would look like this:

`import "../node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol";`

I have faced this issue a few times and have found this to work.